# putty run remote command

Tags: linux, git, putty

I config putty to run remote command after login.

cd /workDirectory/; /bin/bash;

However, after doing this, I cannot use git anymore, complaints: 
git: Command not found.

If I just log on without executing the command, git works just fine.

(I am connecting to rhel from windows)

Comment: Sounds like your `PATH` environment variable is not set correctly. If it works withing a login shell, but _not_ in a normal shell you spawn, then most likely you explicitly set it wrong in your `~/.bashrc` file or similar. Just check its content and see if the git executable is in the paths in there.

Comment: When putty runs a remote command, your shell doesn't source the system-wide profile nor user profile.

Comment: @arkascha thanks, I will try it today